# All queries combined using a UNION operator must have an equal number of expressions

Tags: sql

I am modifying someone else's code to adjust the desired output, however, when I do so, I get an error message: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Code before changes ( works fine ):

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(6)
SELECT  @Period = CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(),112)


select sum(CORPG) as CORPG, sum(FUNDS) as FUNDS, sum(EUCOM) as EUCOM, sum(INSUR) as INSUR, sum(IPIT) as IPIT, sum(LITGE) as LITGE, sum(FINR) as FINR,
       sum(CNSTR) as CNSTR, sum(PLENV) as PLENV, sum(PLENV) as INSOL, sum(EMPLO) as EMPLO, sum(HELSC) as HELSC, sum(BANKG) as BANKG, sum(CONST) as CONST FROM (
Select TARGETFEESBILLED as CORPG, 0 as FUNDS, 0 as EUCOM, 0 as INSUR, 0 as IPIT, 0 as LITGE, 0 as FINR,
       0 as CNSTR, 0 as PLENV, 0 as INSOL, 0 as EMPLO, 0 as HELSC, 0 as BANKG, 0 as CONST
from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'FUNDS' AND PERIOD=@PERIOD 
UNION
Select 0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EUCOM' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EUCOM' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'INSUR' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'IPIT'  and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'LITGE' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'FINR'  and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CNSTR' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'PLENV' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'INSOL' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EMPLO' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'HELSC' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'BANKG' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CONST' and PERIOD=@PERIOD ) Rollup
```

This is the changed code ( wont work ):

```
DECLARE @Period CHAR(6)
SELECT  @Period = CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(),112)


select sum(CORPG) as CORPG, sum(FUNDS) as FUNDS, sum(EUCOM) as EUCOM, sum(INSUR) as INSUR, sum(IPIT) as IPIT, sum(LITGE) as LITGE, sum(FINR) as FINR,
       sum(CNSTR) as CNSTR, sum(PLENV) as PLENV, sum(PLENV) as INSOL, sum(EMPLO) as EMPLO, sum(HELSC) as HELSC, sum(BANKG) as BANKG, sum(CONST) as CONST, sum(COEN) as COEN, sum(CLIM) as CLIM FROM (
Select TARGETFEESBILLED as CORPG, 0 as FUNDS, 0 as EUCOM, 0 as INSUR, 0 as IPIT, 0 as LITGE, 0 as FINR,
       0 as CNSTR, 0 as PLENV, 0 as INSOL, 0 as EMPLO, 0 as HELSC, 0 as BANKG, 0 as CONST, 0 as COEN, 0 as CLIM
from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'FUNDS' AND PERIOD=@PERIOD 
UNION
Select 0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EUCOM' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EUCOM' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'INSUR' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'IPIT'  and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'LITGE' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'FINR'  and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CNSTR' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'PLENV' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'INSOL' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'EMPLO' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'HELSC' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'BANKG' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CONST' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CONST' and PERIOD=@PERIOD UNION
Select 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TARGETFEESBILLED,0 from _ALG_TARGETFEESBILLED_PG where GROUP_CODE = 'CONST' and PERIOD=@PERIOD ) Rollup
```

Some guidance appreciated. The union suggests that there are not enough expressions int he target list, but there is as far as I can see..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of columns are 16 in below query Select TARGETFEESBILLED as CORPG, 0 as FUNDS, 0 as EUCOM, 0 as INSUR, 0 as IPIT, 0 as LITGE, 0 as FINR,
0 as CNSTR, 0 as PLENV, 0 as INSOL, 0 as EMPLO, 0 as HELSC, 0 as BANKG, 0 as CONST, 0 as COEN, 0 as CLIM
from ...

But other queries with unions are having 17 columns.